# AWS Firehose Dynamic Partitioning Inline Parsing with Direct PUT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have created a Firehose that uses dynamic partitioning with inline parsing. It is Direct PUT because I am using a Lambda to get data from an event source that doesn't directly connect with Firehose, and then on the Lambda I am doing `put_record_batch` calls to send the data to firehose. The JSON objects that I am sending to Firehose are like so

```
{
  "customer_id": "123123123",
  ...
}
```

according to the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/dynamic-partitioning.html#dynamic-partitioning-partitioning-keys), when configuring Firehose, I should be able to just specify the following to be able to partition based on customer_id

1. Set Dynamic Partitioning to enabled
2. Set Multi-Record DeAggregation to enabled
3. Set Inline Parsing for JSON to enabled
4. Create a dynamic partition keyname of `customer_id` and a jq expression of `.customer_id`

then if i send through a `put_request_batch` request like the following:

```
payload1 = {"customer_id": "123123"}
encoded_data1 = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(payload1).encode('UTF-8'))

payload2 = {"customer_id": "323232"}
encoded_data2 = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(payload2).encode('UTF-8'))

response = client.put_record_batch(
    DeliveryStreamName='string',
    Records=[
        {
            'Data': encoded_data1
        },
        {
            'Data': encoded_data2
        },
    ]
)
```

I should be able to have the data partitioned based on "customer_id" when it is sent to s3. Instead of that though, I get the following error:

```
{
    "deliveryStreamARN": "<arn>",
    "destination": "<s3 bucket>",
    "deliveryStreamVersionId": 4,
    "message": "Metadata extraction failed because of invalid record.",
    "errorCode": "DynamicPartitioning.MetadataExtractionFailed"
}
```

and the error record that gets stored in s3 says

```
"errorCode":"DynamicPartitioning.MetadataExtractionFailed","errorMessage":"Non JSON record provided"
```

What am I doing wrong? Clearly I sent JSON to firehose.

Comment: why do you base64 encode the payload1 and payload2? That will not be JSON format and cannot be processed by Kinesis then.

Comment: it looks like I misunderstood the documentation for boto3 when it said "The data blob, which is base64-encoded when the blob is serialized" to mean that it should be base64 encoded. I was mistakenly working off of work that had already been started by another contributor and took that for granted. Thank you for pointing out this mistake for me. Please add this as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data you put inside the `'Data'`key should not be base64 encoded. Just do this:

```
response = client.put_record_batch(
    DeliveryStreamName=stream_name,
    Records=[
        {
            'Data': json.dumps(payload1)
        },
        {
            'Data': json.dumps(payload2)
        },
    ]
)
```

AWS documentation is saying that the Data blob will be base64 encoded once serialized.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the put record batch that concatenates all JSONs. Check the option in the Firehose configuration:

**Multi record deaggregation**

Data deaggregation is the process of parsing through the records in a delivery stream and separating the records based either on valid JSON or on the specified delimiter. If your data is aggregated, dynamic partitioning can be applied only after data deaggregation is performed. So if you enable dynamic partitioning to your aggregated data, you must enable multi record deaggregation.

Comment: I specified in step 2 that I have data deaggregation enabled